# let $A$ and $B$ be matrix $n$ x $n$ such that $B-A+BA=2I$. Pove that $BA=AB$

Tags: linear-algebra

let $A$ and $B$ be matrix $n$ x $n$ such that $B-A+BA=2I$. Pove that $BA=AB$

I'm more concerned with how I can derive the prove of this question.I got this equation 
$AB-BA=BAB-B^2A$ and $AB-BA=BA^2-ABA$

Comment: Consider $(B-I)(A+I)=I$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $I=B+BA-(A+I)=(B-I)(A+I)$. Hence $B-I$ and $A+I$ commute, since they are inverse of each other.

It is straight forward to see that $A$ and $B$ commute then, too. (If a matrix commutes with another matrix, it commutes with all polynomial expressions of this matrix)

Comment: I thonk you mean commute, not compute.

Comment: Yes, absolutely :)

Comment: Also the statement in parenthesis brings nothing. We need the implication in the inverse way. So since it is straightforward better to show that AB=A-B+2I also.

Comment: Your comment 'brings nothing', since $A = (A+I)-I$ IS a polynomial expression of $A+I$...Same for $B$.

Comment: Then write it, because what you think in your mind, is not on the paper.

Comment: I could not care less that you did not grasp my hints at first glance. Everybody is free to think a few seconds before saying that something 'brings nothing'.

Comment: Seriously. I would be glad to explain the hint in paranthesis if someone asks. But if you come up and tell me (without even wondering if actually *you* failed to grasp something here) that the hint is useless (which is just **utterly false**), you just lose all credibility in my eyes, because you seem to take it for granted, that everything you do not understand is false. And then you downvote the answer without a reason, because you feel offended...You are a drama queen...